# Check record existence based on value range using SETLL

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg

There is a file with a validfromDate and validtoDateRange fields. Both are key fields in an LF.

Is there a way to check if there exists a record where a date falls between the fromdate and todate value using SETLL or any other opcodes (without having to read through the file)?

The SQL equivalent would be :

```
select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1 a where exists (
SELECT * FROM ipldtad.iplmai WHERE current_date
 between VALFRDATE and VALTODATE       )
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to read through the whole file, but I think you need to read one record after the SETLL.

```
setll (from) myfile;            
if %found();                      
   read myfile;                 
   if keyfld <= to;               
      have_record = *on;        
   endif;                       
endif;
```

Comment: but what if the first found does not satisfy the condition? It would indicate there is no record with  keyfld <= to whereas , there might be other records later in the file which satisfies this condition.

Comment: If the first %found is false, it means there is no record with a key later than the key for the setll. For SETLL, %FOUND means there is a record with a key greater than or equal to the key.

Comment: Apologies, my previous comment was wrong. What I wanted to say was if the first found record does not satisfy  "keyfld <= to; ", but another record does, this wouldn't work would it? Because, there is no check for further records.

Comment: Let's say your keys are simple character values, and the records have keys a b g k m. If from='d' and to='h', setll 'd' will return %found, the READ will get the record with key 'g', which is <= 'h', so there is at least one record between 'd' and 'h'. If from='d' and to='f', setll 'd' will return %found, the READ will get record 'g' which is not <='f', so there is no record between 'd' and 'f'.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the solution to the problem is:

Suppose we have a physical file containing fields

```
(DTEFROM, DTETO)
```

and a set of records

```
#1 (01FEB23, 05MAR23)
#2 (01MAR23, 30MAR23)
#3 (05MAR23, 10MAR23)
#4 (05MAR23, 12MAR23)
#5 (15MAR23, 20MAR23)
```

There is a logical file for it (index)

```
myFile(DTEFROM)
```

by DTEFROM field
Suppose we need to find a record for which

```
DTECHK = 13MAR23
```

lies between DTEFROM and DTETO.

I would do like this:

```
setGT (DTECHK) myFile;
readp myFile; // read record #4

dow not %eof(myFile);
  if DTECHK <= DTEFROM; // true for record #2
    hasRec = *on;
    leave;
  endif;
  
  readp myFile; // read records #3, #2, and so on...
enddo;
```

[setGT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=codes-setgt-set-greater-than) will set the pointer before the first entry for which DTEFROM > DTECHK (or, if you like, after the last entry that satisfies the left end of the range we are looking for).
Then it is enough for us to read the record "back" (readp), checking the condition on the right border of the range (DTECHK <= DTEFROM) until we find the desired record (this will be record # 2) or reach the beginning of the file (readp will return % eof=true).